# How to add a class name to div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script that calls my onepage-scroll.js script. How can I set the class name for `div` (which is a container) in case of this script? I've broke my head of trying to solve this problem - unfortunately my javascript knowledge is too poor at the moment and I'd appreciate any help.

```
jQuery(".main").onepage_scroll({
   sectionContainer: "div",     
   easing: "ease",               
   animationTime: 1000,             
   pagination: true,                
   updateURL: false,                
   beforeMove: function(index) {},  
   afterMove: function(index) {},   
   loop: false,                     
   keyboard: true,                  
   responsiveFallback: false,                        
   direction: "vertical"
});
```

Comment: one_page_scroll function should return a jquery object on which you can call further functions.

Comment: jQuery(".main").addClass("className")

Comment: the `.onepage_scroll() ` refers to this [plugin/lib](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll/blob/master/jquery.onepage-scroll.js)

Comment: It is expected you do a little searching / research before posting a question.  A simple search for your title will produce hundreds of duplicates.  If you have tried to add a class and failed, you should show that code and explain why it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
let a = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
a.classList.add("class-name");
```

To understand the classList concept you can check here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: I wondering why this is the accepted answer, the OP is already using jQuery on that element, might as well chain / use it again

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @anuragb26 in the comments, it is not the purpose of onepage scroll to do that.

You could extend the plugin because internally the element is accessible through `this.el` but the easiest solution is just to do it separately with

```
jQuery(".main").addClass("className")
```